# Records not deleted from SphinxQL

Tags: sphinx, sphinxql

while executing the below query i am getting error. can any one please , suggest to fix that issue

delete from RTindexname where dateupdated > 1397063119 and dateupdated < 1397056434;

sphinxql: syntax error, unexpected IDENT, expecting ID near 'dateupdated > 1397063119 and dateupdated < 1397056434

Comment: What version of Sphinx? Arbitary filters only supported since 2.2.1-beta

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a more recent version of sphinx. As noted in comments above, support was added later than the version you using.